# JQuery's hover function does not display the alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I am trying to show an alert box with the message "Let's have fun!" when the hover occurs. It has to use a jQuery script block that includes the ready event, and a jQuery statement to listen for the hover event in the main element. Then using JavaScript to display the alert box.
The code below is what I have, BUT it doesn't display the alert mssg when I hover the to the hyperlink of "let me see".

I've researched online but doesn't get what is the mistake.

```
<head>
    <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#').hover(function(){
            alert("Lets have fun!");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<main>
<p>Now Now Now <a href="#">Let me see</a></p>
</main>
```

Comment: `"#"` is not a valid selector.

Comment: It is not going to match the href. Take a look at jQuery selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a

> CSS selector

. Hope this helps!

```
   $("a[href='#']").hover(function () {
        alert("Lets have fun!");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, the "#" represents id's, like `<a href="" id="#"></a>`.

Try this, `$("[href='#']")` instead.

```
$("[href='#']").on('hover', function(){
   alert('Hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('* a[href="#"]').on('mouseover', function() { // For all elements <a> that have href="#"
    alert('worked!');
  });
});
```

If you want the effect "onmouseover"